# Send params as part of url in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following form

```
<%= form_for :key, url: unblock_keys_path, :html => {:method => :get} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :value %>
  <%= button_to "Unblock", method: :get %>
<% end %>
```

Which works fine when I enter key values in the text box. But i want the user to be able to access the endpoint directly from the url as well.

Right now the `params` this request generates are:

> {"utf8"=>"✓", "key"=>{"value"=>"x0vdPYWb9nAfyNjFS-UAGQ"},
>   "authenticity_token"=>"+Oi45DHYpPAiNbKrw5kNjWMVrQgCyLsBkhVb7huB0dr+xm/oKXxzTShajVUYEWxl9qlFLfjWsP4C4JM30DTGoA==",
>   "controller"=>"keys", "action"=>"unblock"}

**url**: `http://localhost:3000/keys/unblock?utf8=✓&key%5Bvalue%5D=x0vdPYWb9nAfyNjFS-UAGQ&authenticity_token=%2BOi45DHYpPAiNbKrw5kNjWMVrQgCyLsBkhVb7huB0dr%2Bxm%2FoKXxzTShajVUYEWxl9qlFLfjWsP4C4JM30DTGoA%3D%3D`

I want to be able to access `localhost:3000/keys/unblock?<key_value>`

What changes do I need to make in my request and routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `localhost:3000/keys/unblock?<key_value>` is not a valid url*.  The `?` denotes the start of the params, and then everything after that needs to have the form "name=value", joined with "&".

Do you mean `localhost:3000/keys/unblock/<key_value>`?

If so then add a route like

```
get '/keys/unblock/:value', to: 'keys#unblock'
```

This will send eg `/keys/unblock/foo` to your unblock action, with `params[:value] = "foo"`

*note - technically it's not illegal, but it's poorly formed and almost certainly not what you want to do.